# Cake PHP, MAMP & GIT - Helpers Not Resolving

Tags: git, apache, cakephp, mamp

The problem I have was introduced in migrating from a working remote version to a local version of the codebase.  If I access the front page via "/", the page renders correctly and no errors are reported. However, if I access another view, say "users/login", I receive the following error and the page fails to load (even though the page does work remotely).

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function css() on a non-object 
  in /app/View/Elements/doc_header.ctp on line 28
```

The line number reported corresponds to this code.

```
 echo $this->Html->css('global.css');
```

In both Controllers, I am declaring the proper helpers. Again, it works remotely with unmodified Controller and View code. It would seem I've got some issue with my cake or apache configuration. I am using Cake v 2.1.3. Have any ideas?

Additionally, I used git to clone the remote codebase, and to transport it locally. Perhaps this is where I've gone wrong. Know of any common pitfalls when using Git and Cake?

Comment: Does `localhost/index` actually exist? Unless you have a specific route set up, `localhost/index` would point to the `index` action of the `IndexController`.

Comment: No, I don't have an IndexController. I'm probably just explaining this poorly. I can access my PagesController via "/", which loads my "View/Pages/home.ctp". I haven't tracked down how that's the case in the code (perhaps it's the default interaction), but that content loads just fine. It is strange that there isn't a "home" action in the PagesController though, only "display," so there must be some redirect happening here.

Anyways, it's when I nav. to other pages (that are working remotely) that I have issues, and PHP complains that my helpers are non-objects.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Hoff. It prompted me to test a few more things and to clarify my problem, which I've now edited.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
echo $this->Html->css('global');
```

->css already adds that .css to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That won't fix my problem, but it is good to know.

Comment: did you add the Html helper this to your AppController? e.g. public $helpers = array('Html'); to make it available everywhere?

Comment: Yes, that's just where I added it, in the AppController. It works remotely with the same code. I suspect maybe I've had an issue transporting the codebase to local.